# Why might sed not make any change to a file?

Tags: sed

**Short question:**

Why might sed not make any change to a file and is there any way to check?

**Long question:**

I've tried running a sed command that had always worked with my files before. I learned this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46505221/using-sed-to-remove-spaces-that-are-not-between-letters) back in September. Each quarter I get 4 huge files with a bunch of white space and a column that should be one, but is split in to two. I run the following command to skim the white space and merge the 41st and 42 columns:

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/ \{1,\}"/"/g' -e 's/" \{1,\}/"/g' -e 's/","//41' original_file.txt
```

For the first time yesterday, nothing happened at all. It waits about 3 seconds and then nothing happens, whereas typically it should take 20-30 minutes. I check the file and the spaces are still there. I have 3 times the size of the file still free on the system and twice the file size available in RAM (512GB ram), not that the ram matters, just wanted to throw that in.

I tried writing it to another file using

```
sudo sed -e 's/ \{1,\}"/"/g' -e 's/" \{1,\}/"/g' -e 's/","//41' original_file.txt > formatted_file.txt
```

This creates `formatted_file.txt` but it's completely blank.

Can anyone tell what I'm doing wrong or how to check the issue?

EDIT:

The sample input can be see on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46505221/using-sed-to-remove-spaces-that-are-not-between-letters) except that there are over 300 columns.

Comment: Are you running the command in a system where the same command has worked before?

Comment: Is it possible that space (`0x20`) characters have been replaced by tabs (`0x09`)? You could use `\s\s*` instead of ` \{1,\}`

Comment: @hegez. Yes. It's the same system. This would have been the third time importing the files and running this command on them.

Comment: @Hauke Laging. That's a good idea. I'll check now.

Comment: I just checked in vi. They are spaces; ascii 32 or hex 20.

Comment: Maybe the file format is slightly different and the regexes fail? E.g. are the double quotes there? Is the number of columns >= 42?

Comment: please edit your question and add some sample input and expected output, showing a representative sample of good (non-problematic) records and bad records.  Remember to anonymise your sample data if it contains any personal or sensitive information.

Comment: This seems unrelated to any regexp matching issue or whitespace trap, otherwise the try with outputting to `formatted_file.txt` would duplicate the file, but not create an empty file. I'm not sure whether this is related to `sed` at all.

Comment: what if you do `sed 's/ *"/"/g; s/" */"/g; s/","//41' original_file.txt` without redirecting the output? Is the desired output printed? This would mean that there is no `sed` problem, but something that prevents files to get written (without giving an error). Btw, why do you use `sudo` in the second example? If you are not allowed to write to `formatted_file.txt`, the `sudo` doesn't help you, because the redirection `>` is performed without priviledges.

Comment: Try running `sed` under `strace` (or equivalent if not on Linux) as in `strace sed...` or `sudo strace sed...`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas That sounds promising. I'm researching strace to see how to use it. I've never heard of it before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In comments, it was discovered that the input file is in [big-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) format rather than plain old 7-bit ASCII or 8-bit extended ascii. UTF-16 is a 2-bytes-per-character format, and if used to encode plain ASCII, the "ASCII" character have `0x00` (a NUL byte, displayed as `^@` by `cat -A`, `less`, and other programs) as the first byte of the 2-byte pair (big-endian.  reversed for little-endian).

The fix is to convert the file to plain ASCII.  e.g. instead of using the standard `fromdos` or similar utility to convert CR-LF (dos/windows line-endings) to LF (unix line-endings), you need to do something like the following to convert the text into a format usable by the remainder of the `sed` script:

```
sed -e '1 s/^\xff\xfe|^\xfe\xff//; s/\x00//g; s/\x0d$//'
```

This `sed` script:

- strips the `0xfffe` or `0xfeff` byte-order markers form the beginning of the first line.
- removes all NUL characters from all input lines, wherever they occur.
- removes the carriage-return (`0x0d`) character from the end of any line

Note: this is only suitable for UTF-16 encoded text that contains only characters that would otherwise be ASCII.  It will completely mangle any UTF-16 text file that contains other kinds of characters (e.g. non-english text).

Finally, `perl` has excellent support for text in a variety of common formats, including plain ascii, UTF-8, UTF-16, and more.  It has library modules for working with and converting between all formats.  It is fairly easy to convert simple `sed` scripts to `perl`, so a perl version of the script might be as simple as (untested, but it might even work):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use feature 'unicode_strings';

while(<>) {

  s/^\xff\xfe|^\xfe\xff// if ($. == 1);  # strip Byte Order marker from 1st line

  s/\x0d$//;  # strip CR from each end-of-line
  s/ *"/"/g;  # get rid of all spaces immediately before " characters
  s/" */"/g;  # get rid of all spaces immediately after " characters

  # A very primitive split(). Should use a real CSV parser here, like the
  # Text::CSV module which properly copes with embedded quotes and commas etc
  # in string fields.   This would also allow proper processing of each field to
  # remove any extra whitespace characters rather than the quick-and-dirty hack of
  # global regexp substitutions above.
  my @fields = split /,/;

  # perl arrays start from zero.  This appends the "fake" field 42 onto field 41,
  # and then deletes field 42.
  $fields[40] .= $fields[41];
  delete $fields[41];

  print join(',',@fields), "\n";
}
```

---

## Old answer that still contains (IMO) useful info:

`awk` is a better tool for this job than `sed`.

For example, with GNU `awk` (or any other `awk` that understands PCRE like `\s` and `\S`):

```
awk '{$0=gensub(/\s*(\S+)/,"\\1",42)}1' original > fixed
```

That merges columsn 41 & 42 by removing any spaces immediately preceding column 42.

For non-PCRE `awk`, use `[[:space:]]` instead of `\s` and `[^[:space:]]` instead of `\S`:

```
awk '{$0=gensub(/[[:space:]]*(\[^[:space:]]+)/,"\\1",42)}1' original > fixed
```

Also, depending on the exact nature of the input file, `perl` may be an even better tool for this job than `awk`.  For example, it has modules for parsing CSV files and working with the individual fields in a CSV record.

---

BTW, IMO that `sed` script is horrible, not least because you're using multiple `-e` args rather than a single sed script with `;` as command separator.  If you want to use `sed` then at least use it effectively and efficiently.  Your `sed` script is better written as:

```
sed -e 's/ \{1,\}"/"/g; s/" \{1,\}/"/g; s/","//41' original > fixed
```

or even:

```
sed -e 's/ \{1,\}"/"/g
        s/" \{1,\}/"/g
        s/","//41' original > fixed
```

You'll still need to fix the bug, but at least you'll have something more readable to debug - which makes it FAR easier to see where the problem might be.

Also BTW, `-i` or `--in-place` isn't as "in place" an edit as you might think.  It works by creating a temporary file and then mv-ing it into place afterwards.  This breaks anything that requires the inode to remain the same, including hard links.

It's far better to write the changed output to a temporary file (e.g. temp.txt) and then `cat temp.txt > original.txt; rm temp.txt` - that overwrites the original file with the changed version, while still keeping the same inode.

Comment: The script can be further simplified to `sed 's/  *"/"/g; s/"  */"/g; s/","//41'`. But while everything you write is true, I can't force myself to upvote your answer, as it doesn't address the core problem of the question.

Comment: the core problem of his question is fixing his input data - he may have xyproblem-ed that into "sed will fix it" --> "my sed script isn't working any more", but the underlying problem remains.

Comment: Using multiple `-e` is not going to make any difference in terms of efficiency, compared to semicolons. Internally, they're replaced with newlines. On the other hand, separating sed commands with `;` does not always work for some like `w`, `r` (and `:`, `b`, `t`, `}`... in POSIX)

Comment: yes, i know.  there are a few exceptions (all of which share the common trait that a semi-colon is valid data in the context of what they're doing - filenames, inserting/replacing text lines, etc).    newlines as separator always works.   multiple `-e` scripts also has the problem of being uglier and harder to read.   It's only slightly better than `sed ... | sed ... | sed ... | sed ...` and only just because it doesn't fork multiple seds when one will do.

Comment: Why does awk output something that look like `^@"^@2^@2^@2^@9^@1^@"^@,^@"^@2^@"^@,^@"^@C^@H^@R^@I^@`?

Comment: It's good in the sense that it outputs something, but I don't understand why it's treated like a binary file.

Comment: That looks like it might be a [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) file (a format that is commonly used on windows systems, where each character takes 2 bytes...and "ASCII" character have 0x00 as the low byte).  If it is utf-16, that would explain why the sed script doesn't work those `^@`s (a representation of NUL bytes) are actually in the file -
 they just don't get displayed by default with `less` or `cat`.  Can you add the output of `file --mime-encoding yourfile` to your question.  (or just `file yourfile` if your version of file doesn't support the `--mime-encoding` option).

Comment: If it is utf-16, try adding this sed script before the rest of your sed scripts: `'1 s/\xff\xfe//; s/\x00//g; s/\x0d$//'`.  That will strip the 0xFFFE starting bytes from the first line, as well as all NUL bytes from all lines,  and the carriage returns from the end of each line.   Note: this will result in garbage output if the text file contains other utf-16 characters (e.g. non-english text), it only works for text files that would otherwise be plain ascii if they weren't encoded as 2-byte UTF-16.  Also note: using a language like `perl` that supports UTF-16 would be better.

Comment: Wow @cas. You found the problem and solved too. I should have check the file encoding before but it didn't occur to me that I would be supplied with a different encoding. I'll have to look out for this in the future too. Thank you very much. I kind of wish that sed or awk would create some kind of log with insights regarding what it did.

Comment: i'll update my answer with info about utf-16 at the top.

Comment: BTW, you said you opened the file in vi.  i guess you meant vim.  vim auto-converts between known text file formats (unless you configure it not to), so it wouldn't have displayed the NUL characters.     `hd` aka `hexdump` is one of the most useful tools for examining file formats you're suspicious of - the default output format is a traditional hex dump with hex bytes and corresponding printable ASCII on the same line.